# Fourier approximation only works in range 0.0–1.0

Tags: python, math, fft

Im attempting to recreate a fourier approximation for a python function with a given numerical output (without using external libraries), however my function only works in the range of numbers from 0.0 to 1.0. Ive considered simply multiplying any given input larger than 1.0 to a  negative power of ten, and then multiplying by the positive power once the result has been held.

However, as I am limiting myself to not use external libraries (ie something like `Decimal` or `mpmath`), I feel as though this solution would not work well given python's limited floating-point precision. I feel as though there's a much less 'hacky' solution to this problem, however I am unable to figure out what such may be.

```
e = 2.718281828459045
i_tau = 6.283185307179586j

def integrate(func, a, b, step=0.001):
    total = 0
    while a <= b:
        a += step
        total += func(a)*step
    return total

def fourier_constant(func, n):
    return integrate(lambda x: func(x)*e**(-n*i_tau*x), 0, 1)

def fourier_approx(func, count):
    return lambda x: sum([fourier_constant(func, n)*e**(n*i_tau*x) for n in range(-count, count+1)]).real

series_accuracy = 500
test_value = 0.3        # FIX: only works in range 0.0-1.0

function_to_approximate = lambda x: x*2
approximated_function = fourier_approx(function_to_approximate, series_accuracy)

print(f"expected output at value {test_value} : {function_to_approximate(test_value)}")
print(f"  actual output at value {test_value} : {approximated_function(test_value)}")
```

Comment: Internally Python uses industry-standard IEEE-754 “double precision” values. You will be hard-pressed to find other general-purpose languages that will do better than that. IMO your best bet is to use one of those two libraries. Decimal is not what most would call an "external library" since it's part of the Python Standard Library distributed with the language. Although `mpmath` isn't, it's still an extremely well-done package that's been available for a long time.

Comment: "only works in the range of numbers from 0.0 to 1.0." :what do you mean ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust did you test the program provided? if given a number outside the range of 1, it will respond with an incorrect approximation. If, for say, the function should approximate x*2, and you give it the number 4, you would normally expect a value around 8 (like 8.000123 or 7.998921), however, it responds with incorrect values such as 5.3 and -0.2. Whereas if the input is 0.2, it correctly approximates to nearing the value 0.4.

Comment: Do you really expect the Fourier approximation to behave non-periodically ?

Comment: @martineau: this question has in fact nothing to do with accuracy.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I'm not so sure *you* know what the question is about.

Comment: @martineau: it's about Fourier series, don't you know ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I disagree — but am not going to argue with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is computing a nice triangular wave (which is in no way restricted to the interval [0, 1]). I limited the number of terms to 5 then to 50 to make the *Runge phenomenon* clearly visible.

[image]

[image]

By the way, the computation is perfectly accurate.